How are the individual atoms in a specimen of pure iron bonded to eachother?
I'm confused about the nomenclature related to bonding.
If two atoms are chemically bonded, the combination is called a molecule.
In a specimen (let's say a 3in x 3in cube) of pure iron, all of the specimen's atoms are "bonded" together. So is this iron specimen actually just a gigantic molecule? A gigantic molecule called Fe123385745902...?
What distinguishes the bonds holding the atoms of this specimen together from the bonds that hold molecules together?

Well, metallic character of bonding changes things somewhat, but yeah, you could say it's a giant molecule.

Diamond monocrystal is a more clear cut example.

+1 "clearcut". Yes, crystal clear, planely.

One difference in metallic bond is that those electrons are not strongly localized. There is a sea of electrons. Theoretically, the Pauli exclusion principle has each in a slightly different ground state from all others, merging into a conduction band. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_level and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valence_and_conduction_bands

In the beginning it starts like molecules. Within two iron atoms bonding together the electrons arrange in such a way as to mostly form bonding orbitals. As more iron atoms join, those also provide their electrons to a bonding orbital, the so called valence band. What signifies metals is that not only their valence band is occupied i.e. the highest occupied molecular orbitals but also some part of the lowest unoccupied molecular orbitals is filled. This being due to electron counting. However, as the transition from molecule to large specimen is performed, an additional feature, namely periodicity changes everything. Now, not only do the electrons form stationary bonds but instead due to Bloch's theorem they can be all around the place. The metallic bond is formed which provides additional strength in comparison to the ionic bond.
A good reference and starting point for students might be Kittel >>Solid state physics<< or Ashcroft-Mermin >>solid state physics<<.
